# What does 'what will come of the money' mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

What does **what will come of the money** mean?

> Ohio State University has not said **what will come of the money** it
>   received from Epstein, including the $2.5 million he donated in 2007.

Comment: What will happen as a result of the money.

Comment: It's not a particularly common usage - probably because of potential confusion with near-but-not-quite synonymous *What will **become** of X?*, which is ***very*** common (or at least, ***was***; it's become a bit dated today). Asking *What will come of X?* means *What will happen **because of** X? / What will X **lead to**?* (a result caused by X). Whereas *What will **become** of X?* means *What will **happen to** X? / What will X **turn into**?* (caused by something unspecified) - usually used with the strong implication that something ***bad*** is likely to happen to X.

Comment: What will come of Mother punching the mayor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come) dictionary one of many meanings of "come" is "to happen".

[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/come-of) dictionary defines "come of [something]" as "to be the result of something".

In your case, *"what will come of the money"* essentially means what will happen as a result of getting the money, *"what will happen because of the money, or what will the money lead to"* (as discussed by FumbleFingers in the comments).

Based on these definitions, your sentence would look something like this:

> Ohio State University has not said what will be the result of the money it received from Epstein ...

Similarly

> ... has not said what the university authority will do with the money it received from Epstein ...